# Lectura de códigos de barras en input

Tags: html, jquery, input

Tengo dos tipos de lectores de códigos de barra, uno es el tradicional y el otro lee códigos QR (además de los códigos de barra tradicionales). El problema surge ya que cuando leo con el lector QR, cada código está separado por un Enter(13), y al final de la lectura ejecuta dos veces el Enter, en cambio un lector de código de barras tradicional solo ejecuta un Enter al final de la lectura. Necesito capturar en un arreglo todos los códigos de barra que vengan insertos en el QR, en el ejemplo que pongo acá, si leo un QR que contiene 2 o más códigos de barra, la función se ejecuta N veces, mi idea es que sólo capture al final de la ejecución para evaluar el contenido completo del input.

```js
var arrayQR=[];
function codigodebarra(){
    var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
    arrayQR.push(codigo);
    console.log("Código "+arrayQR);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" onchange="codigodebarra();" >
```

Comment: Cómo lo estás capturando? Activas la cámara del dispositivo o cargas los códigos para su validacion. Agrega por favor más detalles

Comment: A traves de la web, con lectores de códigos de barra, uno tradicional y otro QR

Comment: Podrías capturar cada charCode que indique la pulsación de Intro (13) a medida que vas leyendo los caracteres que llegan del evento que estás escuchando, en ese momento vuelcas lo que has leído en el Array y sigues leyendo la siguiente tanda. Si llegan 2 Intro seguidos, no volcarás nada en el Array en el segundo Intro, ya que no habrá nada que volcar. Esa es una forma de hacerlo, aunque supongo que habrá algunas mejores, es decir almacenar todo lo que se reciba en un buffer y luego hacer el split correspondiente. Saludos

Comment: Por cierto, para hacer lo que quieres con los QR, ya que son multilinea, mejor usas un textarea. Saludos

Comment: humm, estoy seguro que no soy el único que sabe que los lectores vienen con un manual para poder configurar el termino de la lectura y poder agregar o eliminar los enter? y/o agregar cualquier otro tipo de caracter al final o al inicio de la lectura.

Comment: Es efectivo que puedas configurar un lector, pero el código debe estar preparado para leer un código de barra válido, ya que no podemos determinar ni saber cómo el usuario tiene configurado su lector

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma, una vez que finaliza la lectura de códigos de barra, cuento la cantidad de Enter(13) que vienen en el input y luegos los individualizo y así poder guardarlos en un array.

```js
var controladorTiempo = "";
var cantidad=0;
var posicion=[];
var arrayQR=[];

function codigoAJAX() {
    var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
    var numero = (cantidad-1) == 0 ? 1 : cantidad-1;

    inicio=0;
    for(i=0;i<numero;i++){
        codigobarra = codigo.substring(inicio,posicion[i]);
        inicio = posicion[i];
        arrayQR.push(codigobarra);
        
        console.log((i+1)+" "+codigobarra);
    }

    cantidad=0;
    posicion = [];
    $("#codigo").val('');
}

$("#codigo").on("keyup", function(e) {
    var codigo = $("#codigo").val();
    largo = codigo.length;

    if(e.which == 13){
        cantidad++;
        posicion.push(largo);
    }

    clearTimeout(controladorTiempo);
    controladorTiempo = setTimeout(codigoAJAX, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo">
```